# How to Display 1 name from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Hi I have this in my database and I wish to display only one of each Company name from databse.

this is an e.g.

```
RecordID | CompanyName| OrderDate
1        |   Java     | 1 Dec 2013
2        |   Java      | 3 Dec 2013
3        |   ASP      | 10 Dec 2013
```

The result I want:

```
Java        
ASP
```

and not display

Java
Java
ASP

How can it been done?

Comment: I know it Just that I can not get the reult only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CompanyName, COUNT(*) as TotalOrder
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Company c ON c.CompanyID = o.CompanyID
GROUP BY c.CompanyName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Thank for your help now I know why mine can not because I miss up the Order by thank for the help

Answer (score 3):

You should try

```
SELECT t1.CompanyName, COUNT(*) AS TotalOrder
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.CompanyID = t2.CompanyID
GROUP BY t1.CompanyID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: How can you select t1.CompanyName if you're grouping by CompanyID?

Comment: @Vland: take a look at this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2be40/1

Comment: That's interesting, in SQL Server and PostgreSQL it gives an error: Column 'table1.CompanyName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Vland: yes, I know this works only on MySql; I used this because I don't like to group by names: even if it shouldn't happen, names can be the same for different companies and with your query you wrongly sum their records... ;D

Comment: My guess is that the guy, with C# and ASP.Net, is using SQL Server as well... ;) anyway I didn't know about this difference. good to know!

Answer (score 3):

This is just a matter of grouping and ordering by count:

```
select c.CompanyName, Count(*) as TotalOrder
from companytable c
inner join ordertable o on c.CompanyID = o.CompanyID
group by c.CompanyName
order by count(*) desc
```